# Ping Azure Private IP from local development PC

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure load balancer with a private IP address of 10.x.x.x which sits in front of several Service Fabric services. All application parameters in the web apps point to this load balancer with different ports.

We are trying to debug some issues from within Visual Studio on our local developer PC but are not able to hit any of the endpoints (which of course, is because it's a private IP's and we are on the outside.

So my question is, how would we go about debugging when we need to ping this private IP? What additional resource/configuration do we need to set up in Azure (or Visual Studio) to be able to connect to/ping this private IP?

Comment: Have you tried running the service fabric services on a local cluster or it that you think the issues may be related to the load balancer/network setup vs the a problem in the services theselves?

Comment: Ed - yes all works fine using a local SFC - the issue seems to be related to the load balancer/network setup.

Comment: Ok, next steps then, have you tried remote debugging [Remote Service Fabric Debugging] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application#debug-a-remote-service-fabric-application) . You would at least know if your request is making it past the load balancer?  Also, what kind of load balancer are you using? I'm assuming 'internal'?  Another thought, create a small VM inside the same VNet and see if you can ping the private IP of the load balancer plus the ip's of your services.

Answer (score 1):

We are using a VPN gateway and a point-to-site VPN, which allows to talk to the VMs inside the VNet "natively".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about